# how can i add vertical lines between curly brackets in visual studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, curly-braces

the vertical lines between curly bracket that contain (functions, clacess, orders..etc)

there is a picture about it :

[image]

the question is how to activate it in my visual studio 2012 ultimate , cause i Don't have it .

---

┐
└─  **Updated** : the solution here :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42346020/7465452

Answer (score 5, accepted):

---

as i recently known this option Not standard feature that included in V-studio 
 so the solution i found for this Question is "Add-In" called : "  **Indent Guides**  "

the Result will be similar to this picture :

[image]

---

> **to add it follow this instruction down below :**

**1 )**  - install the Addin from the the main website : 
................................................................................

- for VS 2010 , or 2012 : http://indentguide.codeplex.com/releases/view/110312
  .............................................................................................................................
- for VS 2015 or abouve : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SteveDowerMSFT.IndentGuides

  .......................................................................................
  or : http://indentguide.codeplex.com/releases/view/624767

  ---

**2 )**  - After Installation complete restart your V-Studio and go to Edit the add-in from :

[image: Tools-->Options...]

then from the right side menu chose :

[image: Options.. --> Indent Guides]

then you get full control of colors and other options you would change to fit your style :

[image]

and if you want to Disable or Enable  this Addin with a shortcut way from the menu go to ( Edit ) then chose :

[image: Edit --> Advanced --> View Indent Guides]

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you searching for a feature of an Addin. This is not a standard feature.

`Productivity Power Tools` Addin for 2015 supports this under the feature "Structure visualizer"

And there ore more...
Check the addins on the machine were you saw it.

Comment: thanks :D i recherche and found a nice addin and i post here :

http://stackoverflow.com/a/42346020/7465452